# How to get remaining memory in SD Card?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, memory, partition

I have 16 GB SD card where I installed Raspbian using Win32 Disk Imager. After burning the image in Windows it shows only around 40+ MB of free space.

Since Raspbian image is around 2 GB where is rest of the memory? In Linux, using GParted I am getting following result (here it shows 12.54 GB unused that itself is the blank memory in card):

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The  image creates 2 disk partitions SDB1 and SDB2 in the image above. SDB1 is formatted as a fat16 filesystem, this partition is the only one seen by Windows and hence the small amount of free space it reports. Gparted sees both the fat formatted partition and the ext4 formatted partition.

By default the image does not use all of the space available on larger SD cards - such as yours. There is an option in the raspi-config file which will run the first time you boot your Pi to expand the root partition and use the SD card's full capacity. If you have already booted the Pi you can access the config options by running:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

To see how much space is available on the Pi enter the following at the command line:

```
df -h
```

ref: [df man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?df)

Comment: I have already config the Pi, so when i connect this card to Ras-Pi still i can able to use that remaining 12 GB right ?

Comment: Yes, since you already expanded the root partition you can use the 12.54 gig that is available on the root partition (sdb2). You don't need to re run the raspi config option (as you already have).

Answer (score 3):

Boot your pi and enter a shell. Then enter

```
sudo raspi-config
```

There should be an option to expand the file system. See for example: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-raspiconfig-to-set-up-your-raspberry-pi.html

Comment: I have already done that

Comment: I thought I would just gave a quick answer. I did not realize a short answer is not very helpfull without some explanation. Sorry for that! Got the message. Thanks for the note below.